# react createContext with class generictype build error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a junior frontend engineer and I trying to createContext name StoreContext, which has initial parameter 
type is 'class'. here is my codes
 ( I set my project with npx create-next-app)

```
import React,{createContext} from 'react';
import {TodoList} from './TodoList';

export const StoreContext = createContext<TodoList>({} as TodoList);
export const StoreProvider = StoreContext.Provider;
```

I use typescript and there is a compile fail in line 4

```
export const StoreContext = createContext<TodoList>({} as TodoList);
```

> unexpected token, expected ","

problem occurred at {} as Todolist

I tried to fix it with install some babel modules, but didn't work. here is my package.json and .babelrc, babel.config.js

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobx-sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.7.7",
    "mobx": "^5.15.1",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^1.5.2",
    "next": "9.1.7",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/node": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@types/node": "^13.1.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring"]
  }
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-react","@babel/preset-env"],
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",{"useBuiltIns":true}]
  ],
  };
```

how do I fix compile error? 
and what's the name of that syntax

> {} as TodoList

Comment: `{} as TodoList` a "cast". Used to tell typescript that an inferred type is actually something slightly different.

Comment: @AlexWayne thankyou, can you post or link any examples?